# Installed windows w/ bootcamp on Macbook pro, don't see bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, macbook, boot-camp

so I installed windows 7 using the bootcamp assistant on Mac OS X, everything went fine, but it automatically always boots into Windows 7? I don't even have the option to choose which OS? why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try holding the Option <kbd>⌥</kbd> key while starting up your computer?

If you're able to start the startup manager that way, you may be able to set the default start-up volume by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while clicking on an arrow under the volume of your choice (depending on your model).

Answer (score 3):

As has already been mentioned, you can hold down the Option key immediately after turning on the computer to get the boot manager. [apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1310)

You can also select the default OS (automatically boot to OS X instead, for instance) in a couple of places.

In OS X, open System Preferences and select Startup Disk. Then click on the OS you want to be the default.

In Windows 7, there is a similar option in the Boot Camp software that should be accessible down in your System Tray. If you haven't installed the Boot Camp drivers yet, you should. They make life a million times better while using Windows on a Mac.